# spring boot log to file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and when distributing it I tell the people to start it with `java -jar myapp.jar`. I want that a log file is written. If I have an `application.properties` file in the same directory as my jar it works fine. This would mean I either have to distribute the `application.properties` file or tell the user to create one - too error prone. I want that I have the log configureation inside the jar file that the log file is written to the folder where the jar was started from, or to a fixed location, e.g. "C:\temp" I tried to have the application.properties file in my Eclipse project at different locations but it never seems to get picked up. What do I have to do to achieve this?

```
application.properties:

logging.file=myapplication.log
```

Comment: One thought is that you will probably end up with many properties in the application.properties file. You could also set the property on the command line too so that users could change it without risking messing about with this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) you should place application.properties in root of your classpath.

Depending on your project setup, this is typically `src/main/resources`  for Maven project.

To give you exact answer, share details about your project.

Comment: I have trouble how to verify what my classpath root is, I assumed it is src/main/java in my project, that is my only source folder which contains my package and classes. If I have the application.properties file there, I don't get the wanted result.

Comment: src/main/java is for *.java files only (by default). Create src/main/resources and put file there.